# How to prevent quotation marks in title from becoming "too smart"?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, title

When one puts plain quotation marks `"..."` in a question title, I think they're smartly converted to opening- and closing- quotes when displayed.  But in the editor, it still appears as plain quotation marks.

Sometimes, the quotation marks in title are used to mark string literals, and smart conversion is not a Good Thing in this case.

Is it possible for a poster to prevent plain-to-smart quotation mark conversion when the need arises?

Answer (score 5):

It was not possible to do this…until now. We have now disabled all [Smarty](https://daringfireball.net/projects/smartypants/)-like modifications text in titles.

From now on, the title text saved for the post is the title text that will be displayed.

If folks want em-dashes (`ALT-0151`) and fancy quotes (`ALT-0145` through `-0148`) to appear in titles, they are welcome to add them. But we won’t convert it automatically any longer.

> we’re no longer the
> smarty-pants who makes changes
> to typography